# Nodejs swagger auto gen integration

Tags: node.js, swagger-codegen

I need to develop an API using NodeJS and also need to develop documentation for API also. I integrated with swagger auto-gen for swagger.json creation. But the swagger.json not generating properly if I used routes.js as below

```
    var express = require('express');

    module.exports = function(app) {
    var userController    = require('../controller/userController');
    var apiRouter = express.Router();
    var routerV1 = express.Router();
    var routerV2 = express.Router();

    app.use('/admin', apiRouter);
    apiRouter.use("/v1", routerV1);
    apiRouter.use("/v2", routerV2);
 
    routerV1.route('/users').get(userController.getUsersV1);    
    routerV2.route('/users').get(userController.getUsersV2);
     
   
 }
```

and also mapped these routes.js in swagger.js

Please suggest the best way to generate swagger.js

Do we need to create routes file for all controller?

Answer (score 9):

Version 2 of swagger-autogen added this feature. Previous versions don't recognize routes. In your case, the best way to generate the file swagger.js is:

**file:** swagger.js

```
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')();
const outputFile = './swagger_output.json';
const endpointsFiles = ['./routes.js']; // root file where the route starts.

swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpointsFiles).then(() => {
    require('./index.js');           // Your project's root file
})
```

Update your module to the latest version.

And run your project with: *node swagger.js*

And about the routes file for all controller, you don't need to implement it for each one, but it also depends on the structure of your code. If you have a root route file like the example, this is enough for all sub-routes to be scanned. I hope it helps you. Take a look at this example if you need to:
[swagger-autogen using router](https://github.com/davibaltar/example-swagger-autogen-with-router)

Comment: I would suggest quoting the relevant piece of information, a link to the documentation is not a satisfactory answer; kindly improve your answer to help the community better.